# How can I simulate something heavy?

Tags: physics

I need to convey the feeling that something is heavy in a game-like experience. The environment is web-based, most likely mobile.

Specifically, I need the user to be able to lift/move a chain and get a feeling that it's made of heavy metal parts, not that it flaps around as if it were plastic.

Basically the whole point is to make the user go "wow, this is heavy, not cheap plastic stuff".

Sorry if this is a bit of a wild chase - I'd be grateful for pointers to good solutions out in the world, to be able to use them as examples and checks on whether this is feasible.

Have mercy - new to the forum and in general to this kind of topic.

Comment: Can you show us what this object should look like within your game's perspective and art style? This can help us understand what cues would be appropriate for that context.

Comment: @DMGregory - at this point in time no, I can't. That's because lifting the chain and the feeling of weight is _the whole thing_ here. It's a game-like environment where basically the point is to make the user go "wow, this is heavy, not cheap plastic stuff". Sorry if this is a bit of a wild chase.

Comment: Can you tell us whether it's 2D or 3D even?

Comment: What game engine are you using?

Comment: Are you writing your own physics code? Or using some engine? It sounds to me like you had some experience with joints going awry. Perhaps you find this useful: https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the (hint: understand your physics engine, and mass and gravity are important). By the way, I don't know how the mechanic should work, but selling the weight could benefit from animations and sound design. *And game physics don't need to be realistic. At times increasing gravity unrealistically or something like that is right for game feel, Idk if it is the case here.*

Comment: @DMGregory - definitely 3D

Comment: @Evorlor - my plan is to use three.js (which I am faamiliar with) and cannon.js or ammo.js for the physics (whic seem to integrate well with three.js)

Comment: @Theraot - thanks, the video seems spot on. I am quite familiar with cloth physics simulation from past experiences, but not in gaming, I am peeking into how to get the right type of "feel" in other contexts. Re writing my own code - no, not there yet (and probably won't ever be)